# Canonical / Grand-Canonical average annihilation operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Does anyone knows a simple way to understand why the average value of the creation (or annihilation) operator should be equal to zero in the Canonical Ensemble? Why instead if I'm dealing with a Grand-Canonical ensemble the same averages can be different from zero?

I'm asking this because in the Bogoliubov approximation (in the case of weakly interacting Bose gas) basically we set

$a \sim \sqrt(N_0)$

so as far as I understood the average value of a should be different from 0 and the computation should be done in the Grand-Canonical ensemble.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unconvinced that the ensemble average value of an annihilation operator doesn't vanish in the grand canonical ensemble.  Here's my argument for why it does vanish:

Let $H$ be the Hamiltonian and $\mathscr N = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i^\dagger a_i$ be the number operator.  Let
$$
  |\mathbf n \rangle = |n_0, n_1, \dots\rangle
$$
be the occupation number basis which satisfies
\begin{align}
  H|\mathbf n \rangle &= E_{\mathbf n}|\mathbf n\rangle,\qquad  E_\mathbf n =     \sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon_in_i \\
  \mathscr N|\mathbf n \rangle &= N_{\mathbf n}|\mathbf n\rangle,\qquad  N_\mathbf n = \sum_{i=0}^\infty n_i
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
  a_i|\mathbf n\rangle &= \sqrt{n_i}|n_0, \dots, n_{i-1}, n_i-1,n_{i+1}, \dots\rangle \\
a^\dagger_i|\mathbf n\rangle &= \sqrt{n_i+1}|n_0, \dots, n_{i-1}, n_i+1,n_{i+1}, \dots\rangle
\end{align}
The ensemble average of any annihilation operator $a_i$ is
\begin{align}
  \frac{1}{Z}\mathrm{tr}(e^{-\beta(H-\mu \mathscr N)} a_i) 
&= \frac{1}{Z}\sum_{\mathbf n}\langle \mathbf n| e^{-\beta(H-\mu \mathscr N)}a_i|\mathbf n\rangle\\
&= \frac{1}{Z}\sum_{\mathbf n}e^{-\beta(E_\mathbf n-\mu N_\mathbf n)}\langle \mathbf n |n_0, \dots, n_{i-1}, n_i-1,n_{i+1}, \dots\rangle\\
&= 0
\end{align}
where the last equality follows from the orthogonality of the basis vectors $|\mathbf n\rangle$.

Let me know if you find an error in this.

Comment: You have $\sqrt{(n_i - 1)}$ and $\sqrt{(n_i + 1)}$ terms missing in anihilation/creation operators.

Comment: Your derivation does not apply to ensembles with broken gauge symmetry in the thermodynamic limit, e.g. to superconductivity.

Comment: @Slaviks Perhaps you'd be willing to elaborate and point out what it is about the argument that would be different in that case so as to enlighten us?

Comment: @joshphysics Will be happy to do as a soon as I get time for that. Your derivation is fine for a finite system, but in the thermodynamic limit the order (and the conditions) of two inifinite limits (for system volume $\to \infty$ and for the sum in the trace) start to matter and can make a qualitative difference.